# Trying to put Array of URL's into a range of cells in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I can see I have 28 entries in an Array of URLs (resultURLs), and when I try to setValues in a range with the same number of entries, I get the message "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]. I am setting an array of 28 entries to 28 rows and 1 column in the Sheet. Why would I get this error? Thanks for your help!

```
function assignEditUrls() {
  var form = FormApp.openById('1gCHxEc1pv3j-NBVc85wv4l4sXDadbLEzVW08iKWrLJg');
    //enter form ID here

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Form Responses');

    //Change the sheet name as appropriate
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var urlCol = 4; // column number where URL's should be populated; A = 1, B = 2 etc
  var responses = form.getResponses();
  var timestamps = [], urls = [], resultUrls = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    timestamps.push(responses[i].getTimestamp().setMilliseconds(0));
    urls.push(responses[i].getEditResponseUrl());
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < responses.length; j++) {
    resultUrls.push(urls[j]);
  }

  sheet.getRange(2, urlCol, resultUrls.length).setValues(resultUrls);  
}
```